# React - How to show skeleton placeholders until Array map function ended

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

I have a country list component that contains country phone codes, country names and their flags using `map()` function so it takes a bit long to load. I need to get the information if `map()` function ended or still working then use it for showing then hiding placeholders. How could I achieve that?

I couldn't find proper solutions on Internet or couldn't use them. Like when using `Promise(all)` in a React Component, I've been having hardness to figure out how syntax should be.

**`<CountryList />` component:**

```js
// Packages I used for countries
import { getCountries, getCountryCallingCode } from "react-phone-number-input"
import countryNames from "react-phone-number-input/locale/en.json"
import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag"

// The array comes from package
const countries = getCountries()

<CountryList>
  {countries.map((country) => (
    <CountryItem key={country} value={country}>
      <ReactCountryFlag countryCode={country} svg />
      <span>
        {countryNames[country]}
        <span>+{getCountryCallingCode(country)}</span>
      </span>
    </CountryItem>
  ))}
</CountryList>
```

**`<CountryItemSkeleton />` component:**

```js
// The package I used for skeleton placeholder
import ContentLoader from "react-content-loader"

<CountryItemSkeleton>
  <CountryItem>
    <ContentLoader>
      <rect x="0" y="0" rx="3" ry="3" width="40" height="30" />
      <rect x="52" y="8" rx="7" ry="7" width="248" height="14" />
    </ContentLoader>
  </CountryItem>
  <CountryItem>
    <ContentLoader>
      <rect x="0" y="0" rx="3" ry="3" width="40" height="30" />
      <rect x="52" y="8" rx="7" ry="7" width="248" height="14" />
    </ContentLoader>
  </CountryItem>
  <CountryItem>
    <ContentLoader>
      <rect x="0" y="0" rx="3" ry="3" width="40" height="30" />
      <rect x="52" y="8" rx="7" ry="7" width="248" height="14" />
    </ContentLoader>
  </CountryItem>
</CountryItemSkeleton>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any async code here so it's not clear where any delays might be coming from and there's definitely nowhere for you to _wait_ for anything to load

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When `CountriesList` component mounts it takes longer time than usual. The country flags which are SVG's load a bit later than texts. Those happen all the time but especially when the computer have background processes. That is what I want to prevent. Isn't that possible to check if that array map function ended?

Comment: Everything here is synchronous (with the possible exception of the SVG loading / rendering) so no, there is no way to monitor the `map()` progress

Comment: Is it possible to achieve what I want by using an asynchronous function? Excuse my ignorance I am a newbie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything here is synchronous so you cannot wait for or monitor the `map()` progress.

What you can try though is loading the country list in an effect hook so that it's populated *after* your component is mounted. On the initial render you can use your *skeleton* component

```jsx
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

// run once on mount
useEffect(() => {
  setCountries(getCountries());
}, []);

// or even with a small delay
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(setCountries, 200, getCountries());
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
  };
}, []);

return countries.length === 0 ? (
  <CountryItemSkeleton />
) : (
  <CountryList>
    {countries.map((country) => (
      <CountryItem key={country} value={country}>
        {/* etc */}
      </CountryItem>
    ))}
  </CountryList>
);
```